# extract date from filename string

Tags: r

Im looking to extract the date from this kind of string format. It is fixed in length and pattern

```
Files/2020/AUGUST/9009142541082020PT019.txt
```

Date will always be in the last 15 to 10 characters of the string: 082020.
Its format will always be %m%Y

So far i have been using `substring(pt19.df$id, 29)` but output will still have additional characters at the end `082020PT019.txt`

can you please advise if there is a more efficient approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get the `basename` and then use `substring`

```
substring(basename(str1), 11, 16)
#[1] "082020"
```

#### data

```
str1 <- "Files/2020/AUGUST/9009142541082020PT019.txt"
```